# Rendering HTML as text in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using Blazor for a documentation project where I need to post code samples for other devs. [This article](https://www.meziantou.net/rendering-raw-unescaped-html-in-blazor.htm) suggested using `MarkupString` as the solution to print the raw code without rendering it.

My `razor.cs` page looks like this:

```
public partial class Sample
{
    public string Html { get; set; } = "<div class=\"top-row px-4\" style=\"padding-top:0px\">";
    public MarkupString Markup { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        Markup = new MarkupString(Html);
    }
}
```

And the `.razor` page looks like this:

```
    Code sample goes here:
    <pre>
        <code>
            @Markup
        </code>
    </pre>
    @Markup
```

When I run the server, both `@Markup` instances are being rendered by the browser rather than printing the raw HTML like I'd hoped to see:

```
<div style="height: 100%;"><!--!-->
    Markup here
    <pre><code><!--!--><div class="top-row px-4" style="padding-top:0px"></div></code></pre><!--!-->
    <!--!--><div class="top-row px-4" style="padding-top:0px"></div></div>
```

[image]

How can I make the blazor page print `Markup` as text without interpreting it?

Comment: Replace `@Markup` with `@Html` .  `Markup = new MarkupString(Html);` is doing the opposite of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create MarkupComponent.razor
as

```
@Markup

@code{
  private string  Markup;

  [Parameter]
  public string Text { get; set; }

 protected override void OnParametersSet()
  {  
     Markup = new MarkupString(Text).Value.ToString(); 
  }
}
```

and use

```
 <MarkupComponent Text="@Html" />

 @code
 {
   string Html = "<div class=\"top-row px-4\" style=\"padding-top:0px\">";
  }
```

and the result is:
[image]

Comment: `MarkupString.Value` is the same as the original Text, and it is already a string. So the short form of `Markup = new MarkupString(Text).Value.ToString();` is just `Markup = Text;`